# Building query to filter on OR conditions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, iqueryable

I'm trying to build a query where I filter news based on themes. Every news item can have several themes. When I filter I want to get every news item that has any of the themes I filter with but what I get is the news items that has all the themes I have chosen.

I have tried loads of different solutions, here is what I have right now. Any ideas?

```
IQueryable<News> news = context.News;

if (themes.Any())
{
  foreach (var t in themes)
  {
    news = news.Where(n => n.Post.Themes.Count > 0).Where(n => n.Post.Themes.Select(th => th.Id).Contains(t.Id)); 
  }
}
return news.ToList();
```

Comment: What does or doesn't this do?

Comment: If I choose themes A and B, this returns only news that have both A and B themes.  I want all news that have theme A or B or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code you can get the themes ids into array and pass it to Contains extention

```
IQueryable<News> news = context.News;
var themesIds = themes.Select(t=>t.Id).ToArray();

news = news.Where(n =>  n.Post.Themes.Any(t=>themesIds.Contains(t.Id))); 

return news.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare `themes` as `HasSet` and use next query:

```
news.Where(n => n.Post.Themes.Any(t => themes.Contains(t)))
```

**UPDATE**: We don't need HashSet here. Array is good enough. Thanks @KingKing and @Dennis

Comment: Why `HashSet`? It will be enough to use array.

Comment: Computational complexity of HashSet.Contains is O(1), but Array.Contains is O(n)

Comment: In ***LinqToObject*** that's true but here actually the query is translated into SQL query and I don't think there is a benefit of local computation here. Array or HashSet should be the same in this case. We can view the generated sql query to understand it more (both should generate the same sql query).

Comment: What "O(1)" are you talking about, if this question is about `IQueryable`? Your `HashSet` will be just enumerated by LINQ provider to build up appropriate query. Enumeration speed of `HashSet` and array is almost identical.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an extensionmethod for your `News` class.

```
public static class NewsExtensions {

public static List<News> GetNewsByTheme(this List<News> news, List<Theme> themes) {
    List<News> result = new List<News>();
    foreach(var theme in themes) {
        foreach(var newsItem in news) {
            ...some logic here
            result.Add(newsItem);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then in your code just call:

```
List<News> newsContainingThemes = news.GetNewsByTheme(themes);
```